# calling another function from WebService

Tags: java, web-services

I have a query regarding calling a java function in one package from other package.

I have 2 projects (e.g. proj1 - simple java project, proj2 - web service project) created in eclipse.

In my Web Service inside proj2 I am calling a function say foo() in class FooClass{} in package funclib from proj1, but getting the error :
   "Exception in thread “main” org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: funclib/FooClass"

I have created proj1.jar and added it in the "build path" as well as "classpath".

If I copy the package funclib from proj1 to proj2 then it works fine. But, I want to keep both packages separately in 2 different projects.
   Does anybody know how can I resolve this error?

Comment: Please post the entire stacktrace

Comment: Where did you add it to the "build path"? within the eclipse project definitions? And when are you getting the exception? It sounds like you are not exporting the proj1.jar or not including it in the classpath when you actually run the proj2. Are you deploying this to a server?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: funclib/FooClass
 at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
 at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
 at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
 at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
 at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)

Comment: at com.classes.ConcatenateStub.concatenateString(ConcatenateStub.java:185)
 at com.classes.ClientCall.main(ClientCall.java:20)

Comment: I am adding it as : proj2(right click)->build path->configure build path->libraries->Add External Jars. And to Proj2 class path as : Run->Run Configurations->Classpath->Add External Jars. I am only deploying proj2. Getting exception shown in previous comment when I run the WebService client (which is proj3).

Answer (score 0):

Having checked the sources out (http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.axis2/axis2-kernel/1.4.1/org/apache/axis2/util/Utils.java#Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext%28org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext%29), presumably this section is at play:

**org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.java**

```
...
// If its a REST response the content is not a SOAP envelop and hence we will
// Have use the soap body as the exception
if (messageContext.isDoingREST() && soapBody.getFirstElement() != null) {
    return new AxisFault(soapBody.getFirstElement().toString());
}
...
```

Which is itself being called from:

**org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperation**

```
...
// rampart handlers change the envelope and set the decrypted envelope
// so need to check the new one else resenvelope.hasFault() become false.
resenvelope = responseMessageContext.getEnvelope();
if (resenvelope.hasFault()||responseMessageContext.isProcessingFault()) {
    if (options.isExceptionToBeThrownOnSOAPFault()) {
        // does the SOAPFault has a detail element for Excpetion
        throw Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(responseMessageContext);
    }
}
...
```

So it appears there was problem while processing response. And as there could be a million reasons for that I encourage you to put a breakpoint here and debug this in order to figure out the root cause.

Comment: Thanks. Will try doing that. However, how did it work when I copy the package funclib from proj1 to proj2?